# Using the symmetry assumption in this familiar probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm revising some probability and have run into this old problem (context: Monte Carlo tests):

Suppose there are random variables $t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_B$ that are independently and identically distributed with some distribution $F$ that is **continuous and symmetric**. With $I$ below denoting the indicator function, we define
$$
R=\sum_{j=1}^BI(t_j>t_0),\quad p=\frac{R}{B},\\
S=\sum_{j=1}^BI(|t_j|>|t_0|),\quad q=\frac{S}{B}\cdot
$$
Because of the i.i.d. assumption and the continuity of $F$, $R$ is uniformly distributed with support $\{0,1,\ldots,B\}$. With $\alpha\in(0,1)$ is such that $\alpha(B+1)\in\mathbb{Z}$, I'm interested in computing

> $$
> \Pr(p\leq\alpha)\quad\text{and}\quad\Pr(q\leq\alpha).
> $$

I can show $\Pr(p\leq\alpha)=\alpha$ (details below) but I keep making mistakes with $\Pr(q\leq\alpha)$. In particular, **I'm not sure how the symmetry assumption fits in**. Can someone please help? If necessary, please assume $\alpha(B+1)/2\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

> **Proof  $\Pr(p\leq\alpha)=\alpha$**. Because $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $\alpha(B+1)\in\mathbb{Z}$, we infer that $\alpha B=\alpha(B+1)-\alpha$ is **not** an integer and satisfies
>   $$
> \alpha(B+1)-1<\alpha B<\alpha(B+1)\implies\lfloor\alpha B\rfloor=\alpha(B+1)-1.
> $$
>   It follows that
>   \begin{align*}
> \Pr(p\leq\alpha)&=\Pr(R\leq\alpha B)=\Pr(R\in\{0,1,\ldots,\lfloor\alpha B\rfloor\})\\
> &=\frac{\lfloor\alpha B\rfloor+1}{1+B}=\frac{\alpha(B+1)-1+1}{B+1}=\alpha.
> \end{align*}

Comment: The symmetry of $F$ is offtopic hence $p$ and $q$ are identically distributed, that is, $P(p\leqslant\alpha)=P(q\leqslant\alpha)$ for every $\alpha$.

Comment: @Did Can you please turn the comment into an answer so that I can accept and resolve this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetry of F is offtopic hence p and q are identically distributed, that is, P(p⩽α)=P(q⩽α) for every α.